# Jq select statement is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: json, jq

[I am writing this command its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeeIg.png)

i want select command to work i am trying to do filter latency but without select statment it is not working. This is the tutorial i have been following https://k6.io/docs/examples/tutorials/get-started-with-k6/analyze-results/ please take a a look and provide me solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `'` for strings in cmd. You have a few options:

- Dump cmd and switch to a proper shell (WSL, Git Bash; even PowerShell should work)
- Use double quotes and escape the inner double quotes
- Store your jq program in a file and execute the file